# Need to add SOAP security token

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I need to set a custom soap header attribute on a jax-ws generated webservice client. I my case all webservice calls must go through a proxy server requiring a specific token (recieved from the web request header) to be present in the soap request header. E.g.:

```
1 CarServiceService service = null;
2 service = new CarServiceService(new URL(url), new QName(qname);
3 CarServiceEndpoint port = service.getCarServicePort();
```

It seems that in line 3 the wsdl is retrieved and my call fails due to the missing security token. Could any one point to direction on how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue from this blog post: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.dk/2009/02/jax-ws-how-to-configure-service-end_17.html

Basically I needed to set the webservice endpoint manually instead of the framework trying to extract the endpoint from the requested wsdl -  which failed.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed example has been mentioned here:

[Creating and Deploying JAX-WS web service on Tomcat 6](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-and-deploying-jax-ws)

This article shows how to create and use `security token`.